# Is there any option to pin and dock my Android Emulator to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I would like to pin and dock my Android Emulator so I can see it from within Android Studio, rather than in a separate window.

Answer (score 8):

In the preferences menu -> tools -> emulator you can now do this
[image]

Comment: This works nicely in Artic Fox 2020.3.1

Comment: Looks a little different, but still works in Hedgehog 2023.1.1

Answer (score 1):

To run the Android Emulator in an Android Studio window, go to: **File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator**, then select the ‘*Launch in a tool window*’ option and click **Apply**
[The Emulator options under preference settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZoRW.png)

You can then access the Emulator window in the Sidebar on the right side of Android Studio.
[The Emulator window in the right Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X54Qs.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature presently under development. Expected in future releases but currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Flamingo or Electric ele, you have to **disable** the checkbox for ***Launch In a tool window*** option located in **settings > Tools > Emulator > Launch in a tool window.**

- After uncheck this option, the emulator will open as a **standalone application** and now you can pin the emulator. So, Android studio and Emulator works side by side.

[image]